# Nifi:how to get only one flwoFile from success queue?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want  to   get  only  first   flowfile   which  was send in  sucess 'queue' from my  executescript  processor    but  i  can't  manage  it  here is  my  code:
AND  THIS CODE  THROWS  EXCEPTION THAT FLOWFILE  HAS  ALREADY   MARKEDFOR TRANSFER

1. how  can  i  remove  other  unused  flowfiles   and  how to  prevent getting  them  with  fist  flowfile(  i  mean when  i  delete  this  remove  command  exceptions  won't  be  present  but   process  will  take  every  flowfile  form sucess  queue  ,  how can i  prevent it?)

   ```
   def List<FlowFile> flowFiles= session.get(1)
   def name="";
   def  count=" ";
   Double   value=0.0;
   def  numb=0;
   if(flowFiles.size()>1){
   session.remove(flowFiles.remove(flowFiles.size()-1))

   }
   List<FlowFile> flowFiles2 = new ArrayList<FlowFile>();
   for(FlowFile  k in flowFiles){
   name=k.getAttribute("realName")
   count=k.getAttribute("count")
   value= count as Double;
   numb=Math.round(value)
   session.transfer(flowFiles.get(0),REL_SUCCESS)


   }   
   session.remove(flowFiles)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to use a List if you want to get one flow file.

How about:

```
def FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
```

You can't call remove and transfer on the same flow file.

If you want to remove it, then it is gone and can't be transferred.

If you want to transfer it to the next queue, then it can't be removed.

Comment: how  can  i  be  sure  that  only one  flowfle  was  sent  and received?

Comment: session.get() will return at most one flow file.

Comment: if  i  have more than 10  flowFile in success  queue ?  how  should  i  get  only one  flowfile  from  it?

Comment: does  nifi  synchonizely sends  every  flowfile  which is  placed  in success relationship

Comment: Is  there  any  way  i can  get  only one  first  flowfile  from  queue?

Comment: Each time you call session.get() it gets the next flow file from the incoming queue... if the previous processor transferred flow files 1, 2, and 3 to success, then the next processor will get flow file 1 on the first session.get(), flow file 2 on the second session.get, and flow file 3 on the third session.get()

Comment: Yes ,  i got it    but  how can  i controll  that  session.get()   will  be   fullfiled  only  once  even  though  there  would  be several  flowfile in sucess  queue

Comment: Also looking for a "take first, drop all others" option!